# How to stop redirecting to custom domain?

Tags: github, github-pages

Some years ago I added a custom domain from free site just to try a new feature of Github. Now that I want to make a page my main url keeps getting redirect to myexpireddomain.com ...

```
http://myuser.github.io  => myexpireddomain.com
http://myuser.github.io/page  => myexpireddomain.com/page
```

and this all results in 404...since domain doesn't exist.

I think I need to remove cname file somewhere. But out 20 repos that I have I don't see any that should cname... which repo is at the root domain. `http://myuser.github.io`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The repository for your main domain is either `myuser.github.io`, as [documented on the Pages website](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages), or possibly `myuser.github.com` in case your site is from before GitHub [started using `github.io` for Pages](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io).

Check the `master` branch for a file called `CNAME` in the repository root.

Comment: there was a repository named `myuser.github.io` i deleted it yesterday in hope that it'd stop redirecting if this was the cause. But it's still redirecting .

Comment: i have about 17 repos... 1 of them was that and another one is page also but it was created today and link is suppose to be `myuser.github.io/reponame`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, is this still happening? These types of changes can take some time to fully propagate. Have you cleared your browser cache? Have you modified your local `hosts` file?

Answer (score 27):

For removal of custom domain, I removed all of the text from the custom domain field in the settings for that particular website, then pressed save. Then, I found out that **you have to clear the browser cache (in google chrome I just cleared all of the browsing data for the last hour)**, otherwise it will still redirect to the custom domain!

Also, make sure that the CNAME file in your repository is deleted. Github pages creates this for you when you add a custom domain.

Comment: After deleting the User page repository (username.github.io), deleting browser cache did the trick for me

Comment: This was definitely annoying. There's no options in chrome://settings to specifically clear this for a website. The only way, without clearing all history in a time range, is to open devtools, turn off network caching, then refresh the page.